# Sharepoint 2013 welcome page redirection issue

Tags: c#, redirect, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am facing a weird issue where I have changed the welcome page of my sharepoint 2013 site to a page called *Home.aspx*, so now my welcome page link looks like *https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/ThisIsSCName/Home.aspx*. When I share the link of the site, to my team as https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/ThisIsSCName, most of the time it works fine and redirects to *Home.aspx*, but sometimes it's redirecting to *default.aspx*, for example, like once or twice in ten times when I load the site, it's redirecting to *default.aspx*. It's so strange. I tried hard to crack the error, but could not. Help me in this issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is happening. Is it happening to a certain set of users or everyone?

but as a workaround, you can redirect from default.aspx to home page by placing a redirect script in content editor webpart on default page.

```
        function Redirect() {
           window.location="http://yourpage.aspx";
        }
```

This will appear as if its redirecting to home everytime.